# ProgressBar is not shown in Rust

Tags: rust, progress-bar

I have a struct with the implementation as shown below:

```rust
use indicatif::ProgressBar;

pub struct Bar {
    pb: ProgressBar,
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn new(len: u32) -> Bar {
        println!("Bar::new({})", len);
        Bar {
            pb: ProgressBar::new(len as u64),
        }
    }
    pub fn increase(&self) {
        println!("Bar::increase()");
        self.pb.inc(1);
    }
}
```

When I call `new` then `increase` functions consecutively as below, the ProgressBar is not constructed. Why?

```rust
let bar = bar::Bar::new(10);
bar.increase();
```

On the other hand, I can run [this code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/indicatif/blob/master/examples/single.rs) successfully. I am new to Rust and I couldn't understand the difference between two.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you by any chance exiting the program immediately after you call `increase`? In which case the progress bar would get erased by your shell prompt when the program exits…

Comment: You are right, the program is terminating and I am not able to see it. Thanks!